# Adding IR remote control to android application in android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, remote-control, infrared

i want my application to be controlled by infrared remote. and the app must run in kitkat version. basically here i am having 4 image views and i want the user to use IR remote to move and select a particular image. Can anyone help me on where to start? Should i stick only to a particular remote, or are the controls in remote same on all remotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last found the solution!!!! :)
Below is the sample code.

```
    public class DpadActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView iv1,iv2;
private static Toast tst;
private int current_position=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dpad);
    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);

    iv1.requestFocus();
    iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilight);


    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iv2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iv1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha hai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER == keyCode
            || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) {
tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT == keyCode) {
tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT == keyCode) {
        tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP == keyCode) {
        if(current_position==1)
        {
            iv2.requestFocus();
            current_position=2;
        }else if(current_position==2)
        {
            iv1.requestFocus();
            current_position=1;
        }
        tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Up Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN == keyCode) {
        if(current_position==1)
        {
            iv2.requestFocus();
            current_position=2;
        }else if(current_position==2)
        {
            iv1.requestFocus();
            current_position=1;
        }
        tst.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Down Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```